woocommerce error code when trying to add custom field after product description
I am trying to add this code in functions.php but it is giving me the error
add_filter( 'the_content', 'misha_add_something_description_tab' );
function misha_add_something_description_tab( $content ){
    if( is_product() ) { // I recommend to always use this condition
        $content .= '<table class="vertical-menu">
    <tbody>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="cabecera"><?php if( get_field('download') ): ?><strong><i class="icon-checkmark"></i>Download:</strong></td>
            <td class="detail"><strong><?php the_field('download'); ?><?php endif; ?></strong></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="cabecera"><?php if( get_field('color') ): ?><strong><i class="icon-checkmark"></i>Color:</strong></td>
            <td class="detail"><strong><?php the_field('color'); ?><?php endif; ?></strong></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>';
    }
    return $content;
};

I want this content to be added after the product description

Use the following code in functions.php or create a child theme. I have used action hook.
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'misha_add_custom_info', 10 );

function misha_add_custom_info() {
  if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
    ?>
    <table class="vertical-menu">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="cabecera">
          <?php if( get_field('download') ): ?>
            <strong><i class="icon-checkmark"></i>Download:</strong>
          <?php endif; ?>
          </td>
          <td class="detail">
            <strong><?php the_field('download'); ?><?php endif; ?></strong>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="cabecera">
          <?php if( get_field('color') ): ?>
            <strong><i class="icon-checkmark"></i>Color:</strong>
          <?php endif; ?>
          </td>
          <td class="detail">
            <strong><?php the_field('color'); ?><?php endif; ?></strong>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php
  }
}

